how to change the directory of vs code snippets
snippets are placed in a folder named appdata\roaming\code\user\snippets (on windows PC )
How do I change that folder?
Would like to place visual studio code snippets in another folder
i want to keep all vs code files and folders including snippets folder in one folder so its easy for me to backup every thing in one go

You can change your whole user-data directory. If you want to change the default user-data directory, you can edit your VS Code application shortcut to add a --user-data-dir <dir> argument sequence. There'll be a lot of stuff to gitignore though, in that case. I suggest you move the User/ subdirectory of your default user-data directory to your custom config files location, and then replace it with a symlink/junction to the new location.
